# I need a few lines of python to make WIF addresses

Tags: address, python, wallet-import-format

I have code which generates WIF keys from hex keys.  It just need a few more lines to generate WIF addresses.

## ------------------------

```
import binascii, hashlib, base58, sys
```

def convert(z):

```
private_key_static = z

extended_key = "80"+private_key_static+"01"

first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(extended_key)).hexdigest()

second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_sha256)).hexdigest()

final_key = extended_key+second_sha256[:8]

WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(final_key)).decode ('ascii')

print (WIF)
```

with open("HEX.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       convert(str.strip(line))

Answer (score 1):

Note: [WIF](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) is a format for private keys, not addresses.  There are multiple address formats, but the most common is P2PKH (**hash** of a *public* key).

I recommend looking that the code for Electrum to learn about how to work with public keys and addresses in Python, (check out [bitcoin.py](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/electrum/bitcoin.py)).  It contains everything you need and is reliable code used by many thousands of users to secure their bitcoin.

Comment: TY  You're right.  I'm a beginner at this.